# MongoDB/Mongoose - Returning documents that are filtered by a date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am wanting to run a monthly check for my users licenses to see if they are expired or not. The user model goes something like this.

```js
[{
 name: 'Steve',
 licenses: [
  {
    name: 'licenseA',
    expiration: '2022-07-30T07:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    name: 'licenseB',
    expiration: '2022-12-30T07:00:00.000Z',
  },
]
},
{
 name: 'Mary',
 licenses: [
  {
    name: 'licenseA',
    expiration: '2022-10-30T07:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    name: 'licenseB',
    expiration: '2022-12-30T07:00:00.000Z',
  },
]
}]
```

I am just wanting the document to be returned if the expiration has passed from the current date

```js
  const curDate = new Date()

  const users = await User.find({
    'licenses.expiration': { $lte: curDate},
  })
```

this function just returns all of the documents regradless of if the date is expired

Comment: In your specific example, every `expiration` date is less than your `yearDate` UNIX timestamp (which is August 2023). Could you please provide some real-life data you are experiencing an issue with?

Comment: I have edited the function, its just suppose to be anything less than current date. i was messing with other stuff and forgot to change back

Comment: What is expected if one license of a user has expired and the other ones are valid